# Does https proxy encrypts the connection to it?

Tags: proxy, https

If I use https proxy, Does the connection and trasfer to the server itself (before the server forwards my request to the destination server) is done via encrypted channel ? (TLS/SSL)

I understand it like the following example:

Client --->encrypted channel---> Https Proxy ----->unecnrypted requests to http server and encrypted requests to https server

Am I correct?

Comment: This question appears to be off topic.   It does not relate to a production environment or meet the standards as outlined in the FAQ.  http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4111/what-is-a-professional-capacity

Answer (score 1):

You might get a better answer here;

https://security.stackexchange.com/

More specifically something like this;

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8145/does-https-prevent-man-in-the-middle-attacks-by-proxy-server

So in short, yes if you use HTTPS your connection is encrypted using public/private key cryptography.  You should note though that if the admin of the HTTPS proxy wants to, they can decrypt your data and snoop fairly easily if they want to - it basically comes down to trust....